# Derivation of $\langle \psi|\psi_n\rangle\langle \psi_n|\psi\rangle = |\langle \psi_n|\psi\rangle|^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

I'm trying to find a derivation for the relationship between $$\int|\Psi(\vec{r},t)|^2\ d^3r = 1 = \int \Psi^*(\vec{r},t)\ \Psi(\vec{r},t) \ d^3r.$$

Is this considered a postulate or is there an intuitive way to explain this?
The reason is the fact that the Bra-ket notation depends on the fact that $\langle \psi|\psi_n\rangle\langle \psi_n|\psi\rangle = |\langle \psi_n|\psi\rangle|^2$, which I can't get to work out by drawing the projections like below, where blue is $|\psi\rangle$ and red is $|\psi_n\rangle$.
[image: drawing]

As one can see in the drawing, the projections do not have the same length, therefor, how can one conclude with $\langle \psi|\psi_n\rangle\langle \psi_n|\psi\rangle = |\langle \psi_n|\psi\rangle|^2$?

I have assumed that $\langle \psi_n|\psi\rangle$ means the projection of $\psi$ on $\psi_n$ as stated in the textbook.

Comment: It seems you've misunderstood the usual [Euclidean dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition). The above relationship is not mysterious if you understood that properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just standard multiplication of complex numbers. If we have a complex number $z$, then $z^*z=|z|^2$

$$z=a+bi$$
$$z^*=a-bi$$
$$z^*z=(a-bi)(a+bi)=a^2+b^2=|z|^2$$

In our case, $z=\langle\psi_n|\psi\rangle$, and $z^*=\langle\psi|\psi_n\rangle$, so the result you want is true. It doesn't matter what the projections actually are.

Comment: So I must assume that we are always working with complex numbers?

Comment: @PhyCoMath This holds for real numbers too. But yes, in QM inner products tend to be complex

Comment: It's just that the projection (if real) for $\psi_n \neq \psi$ as you see in the figure. So I'm assuming some sort of restriction? Am I thinking about this correctly, or is $\psi_n$ and $\psi$ always of the same length, making the projections similar.

Comment: @PhyCoMath In general the inner product $\langle \psi_n\vert\psi \rangle$ is the projection of $\psi$ on the basis vector $\psi_n$ and is a complex number.

Comment: @PhyCoMath I never said anything about the lengths of the vectors themselves. I don't think I follow what you are saying.

Comment: @AaronStevens Okai, so $|\langle \psi_n|\psi \rangle|^2 \neq |\langle \psi|\psi_n \rangle|^2$?

Comment: @PhyCoMath No those are equal. $z^*z=zz^*$ Multiplication over the complex numbers is commutative.

Comment: @AaronStevens So there is an assumption that $|\psi| = |\psi_n|$, which for vectors in Hilbert Space are infinite and my figure therefor is wrong? (colored are the lengths of the vectors).

Comment: @PhyCoMath Not at all. The relation proven in my answer has nothing to do with the length of the vectors. It is not assumed that they are the same length. We are looking at the inner products between the two vectors. We have not said anything about the length of the individual vectors.

Comment: @AaronStevens However in the definition of $z$ you have assumed that the value $a$ and $b$ are of the same values for the projection of **red on blue**, and **blue on red** (besides the conjugate). I'm just trying to understand how it would be graphically interpreted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86516/discussion-between-aaron-stevens-and-phycomath).

Comment: As was stated in chat by Bruce, I was mixing between scalar projection and dot product. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2093527/82781 :)